# is there a way to the set custom headers in the domino-ui file upload request?

Tags: user-interface, gwt, frontend, domino-ui

We have an implementation of double submit cookies anti-CSRF and i need to put a header in the upload form that uses domino-ui. is there a way to set a custom request header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the request instance by adding onBeforeUploadHandler on the fileitem, first you need to add onAddFileHandler and then you get the file item, once you get the fileitem you can add onBeforeUploadHandler and then add the headers you want.